# Gamma function limit

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I've been trying to solve the following limit:

$$ \lim_{{x \to 0^+}} \sqrt{\frac{e^{\Gamma(x)} - e^{-\Gamma(x)}}{\ln(\Gamma(x))}}$$

where $\Gamma(x)$ is the Gamma function and:

$$ \lim_{{x \to 0^+}} \Gamma(x) =  \infty$$

Upon using L'Hopital, I arrived at the $\infty/\infty$ indeterminate form, and further calculations involved derivatives in droves that only made the case more convoluted. I've also tried putting the exponentials in evidence:

$$\lim_{{x \to 0^+}} \sqrt{\frac{e^{\Gamma(x)} (1- e^{-2\Gamma(x)})}{\ln(\Gamma(x))}} = \lim_{{x \to 0^+}} \sqrt{\frac{e^{\Gamma(x)} }{\ln(\Gamma(x))}} \lim_{{x \to 0^+}} \sqrt{(1- e^{-2\Gamma(x)})} = \lim_{{x \to 0^+}} \sqrt{\frac{e^{\Gamma(x)} }{\ln(\Gamma(x))}} \hspace{0,5cm}, $$

albeit, this is only possible if the product of the limits doesn't lead to an indeterminate form, so the attempt above is wrong.

I would argue that the exponential grows substantially faster than the logarithm in the denominator, but still, I'm faced with a contrivance in that we still get a $\infty / \infty$ there. How do I proceed?

Comment: Where did you find the limit?

Comment: @Zima Actually, I took motivation from a limit I had found one akin to that one only involving exponentials. For fun, I started experimenting with the Gamma and Digamma functions, and turns out I arrived at this one by chance. I've been trying to solve it but to no avail so far.

Comment: But $\psi$ is negative on $(0, 1)$ though, making $\ln(\psi(x))$ undefined, no? I’ll admit: I cheated; I used Desmos. It’s kinda obvious once it pointed it out.

Comment: @X-Rui Thank you for the input. I changed the question to now having a Gamma function on the bottom instead of the Digamma function. How should we proceed from here on out?

Comment: $$\lim_{u\rightarrow\infty}\frac{e^u-e^{-u}}{\log(u)}=\infty$$

Comment: @Mittens even after making that u-substitution and applying L'Hopital, there are derivatives to deal with. If you know how to solve this can you provide an answer?

Comment: Why do we need derivatives in @Mittens approach? It is just based on properties of logarithm and exponential function. In particular write the expression as $$\frac{e^u-e^{-u}} {e^u} \cdot\frac{e^u} {u} \cdot\frac{u} {\log u} $$ and the limit of these factors are well known.

Comment: @MicrosoftBruh: It is an obvious fact that exponential growth is faster than linear and that linear is much faster than logarithmic growth. Notice that $$\frac{e^u-1}{\log u}\leq \frac{e^u-e^{-u}}{\log(u)}\qquad u>1$$